# Fade in and out div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My goal: fade in a div with text, after n seconds fade out. Do this again with 4 another divs, without interfere the div before (like showing up when the div before is still on screen) with consistent distances.

Here you can what I want to accomplish: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2PsCgs8rVHE (only the first moments).

Probably I am thinking too complicated.

I tried this for some time (hours, eh) now and tried thousand things. Here is my current code:

```
$('.quote').each(function(divID){
    fadeContent(divID);
});

function fadeContent(childID)
{
    $('.quote:nth-child('+childID+')').fadeIn(1000).delay(8000*childID).fadeOut(1000);
}
```

Before that I create the divs from array (works fine)

```
for(var i = 0; i < quotes.length; i++){
    var quote_container = $('<div>').addClass('quote').append(quotes[i]).css('display', 'none');
    $('.quotes').append(quote_container);
}
```

Appreciate your help a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I **had to** code this: https://jsfiddle.net/dmpk42vd/

Here's an example of how you might go about it with jQuery:

```
$(".txt1").fadeIn("slow").delay(4000).fadeOut("slow");
$(".txt2").delay(6000).fadeIn("slow").delay(4000).fadeOut("slow");
$(".txt3").delay(12000).fadeIn("slow").delay(4000).fadeOut("slow");
$(".txt4").delay(18000).fadeIn("slow").delay(4000).fadeOut("slow");
$(".txt5").delay(24000).fadeIn("slow").delay(4000).fadeOut("slow");
```

EDIT: Added more or less delay depending on text length and made the entire thing work with one class. See comments and answers below for OPs.
I also made this a little bit more like Zelda :)

https://jsfiddle.net/dmpk42vd/2/

```
var delay = 0;
$('.txt').each(function (index) {
   $('.txt').eq(index).delay(delay).fadeIn("slow").delay($(this).text().length * 30).fadeOut("slow");
   delay += 6000;
});
```

Comment: Additional feature - check, how much text is in the div to know how long should be the delay. `...delay($("#that_div").text().length * 20)`. Approx 20ms on one symbol.

Comment: That is awesome! Next time I will provide a working example. I can see now how this help you. With your help I got it working now (and of the Poster below) I really like your "Zelda"-Edition. The length-thing is really helpful and will save this for next code-work. Thanks, both of you.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a slightly more dynamic way, wouldn't require adding additional CSS classes or Jquery

```
var delay = 0;
$('.quote').each(function (index) {
   $('.quote').eq(index).delay(delay).fadeIn("slow").delay(4000).fadeOut("slow");
   delay += 6000;
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/80w1hnqh/

Comment: That's great! Mind if I merge that with my answer?

Comment: Yeah sure merge away :)

Comment: Thanks man. I would really like to get you the "solved"-badget. Because of the summarized answer, which is because of that more helpful, get the checkmark, although I really like to get you one, too. Thanks again for your great answer!